# Flutter integration test как сделать Tap по StyledText

Tags: flutter

Подскажите, есть ли способы как то нажать на текст в теге, кроме как по координатам

```
StyledText(
              text: localization.promoLabel,
              style: typography.captionRegular.copyWith(
                color: colorScheme.palette.calendarRange,
              ),
              key: IntroPageScreenKeys.promoLabelKey,
              tags: <String, StyledTextTagBase>{
                'link': StyledTextActionTag(
                  (String? text, Map<String?, String?> attrs) => navigateToRules(
                    context: context,
                    rulesUri: rules,
                  ),
                  style: typography.captionRegular.copyWith(
                    color: colorScheme.palette.calendarRange,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                ),
              },
            ),
```

Comment: А с обычным путём вроде `tester.tap( find.by... )` возникает какая-то проблема?